# How to "swap" staging and production slots in release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a setting in Azure Devops release pipeline to "swap" deployment slots, similar to how it can be done in Azure Portal with source/target?

[image: swap]

We have a stage where after the developer has verified the deployment on staging environment, he would want to enable the swapping to production, but I cannot find a setting like that. The only deployment slot setting I came across in Azure Devops is specifying the slot in App Service deployment task, but theres no swapping mechanism that I see...

[image: slot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved in an Azure DevOps release pipeline.

> The only deployment slot setting I came across in Azure Devops is specifying the slot in App Service deployment task...

Yes, this is the first step - deploy your app to a slot using the above-mentioned task:

[image]

Then, add a new `Azure App Service Manage` task to the job:

[image]

Which you can then configure like:

[image]

You just need to ensure that the `Source Slot` points to the same one you've deployed to in the `Azure App Service deploy` task.

Comment: How can this be achieved, if deploying to an on-prem IIS?